# Using btn_circle_normal - android

Tags: android-button

I tried to use the standard icons provided by android as the background for my ImageButton using:

```
 android:background="@android:drawable/btn_circle_normal"
```

btn_circle_normal seems to be present in the sdk directory. However, I get the error:
error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'background' with value '@android:drawable/btn_circle_normal').

What could be the possible cause for the same and also the solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

these Ressources are private and you may not use them in your styles. You could however create your own style, that mimics the same thing. Just download the extracted rounded PNGs and create a file like rounded_buttons in your src/drawable Folder. You can find a good [tutorial](http://www.aiti-aptech.edu.vn/index.php/cach-tao-button-hinh-tron-trong-android) (Google-Translate it first).